# IBOutlet UITableView visible in simulator but not on device

Tags: iphone

I have developed a split view based universal application which runs as a navigation based application on iPhone. after login table view appears which is the root view in split based application.

The code works fine on iPhone simulator but when i try running it on device, ,the table view does not appear.

I tried debugging it and the problem is that table view is not being allocated memory when i am running on device whereas on simulator the same code allocates memory to IBOutlet table view.

I dont understand why the same object is not being allocated memory when i try running it on device.

Comment: so, may be the temp file of the project. it should give same result if you Clean the project and Rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was a relatively silly mistake. I had not made xib for iPhone, and so table view was not conected to any interface builder object. But why the same code runs on simulator is still a mystery.